# How can decrease runtime of for loop creating dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a pandas dataframe called full_df. It has a dimension of (348204,18). I am creating a dictionary using this data as follows.

```
wx_data = {}
key_len = range(count)
n = range(len(full_df))
for i in n:
    #create key
    key_len = str("%02d" % (full_df["year"][i])) + \
    str("%02d" % (full_df["month"][i])) + \
    str("%02d" % (full_df["day"][i])) + \
    str("%02d" % (full_df["hour"][i])) + \
    str("%02d" % (full_df["minute"][i]))

    wx_data[key_len] = full_df.iloc[i].values.tolist()
```

The for loop in my code is very slow. How can I make this more efficient?
thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try use [joblib](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

def convert_df(full_df):
    #create key
    key_len = str("%02d" % (full_df["year"])) + \
    str("%02d" % (full_df["month"])) + \
    str("%02d" % (full_df["day"])) + \
    str("%02d" % (full_df["hour"])) + \
    str("%02d" % (full_df["minute"]))

    return key_len, full_df.values.tolist()

wx_data = Parallel(n_jobs=-1)(delayed(convert_df)(row) for _, row in full_df.iterrows())
wx_data = dict(wx_data)
```

Comment: Thank you Dima First. I get an error message saying no module named joblib. I'm using python 2.7. this might be why.

Comment: @fede.dica92 try install it: `pip install joblib`